# Are atoms compressible?

Tags: atoms, density, matter

Liquids are not compressible, but what does *compressible* mean? Does it mean the increase in the density or decrease in volume? Or something else? Why are liquids incompressible, in a way nothing should be compressible because atoms are compressible, right? Is there a maximum density an object can acquire?

Comment: It didn't really make sense to post the set of questions twice, so I've removed the second set & cleaned up the grammar of the original. I believe I've not changed the intended meaning, but feel free to modify the post using the edit button to correct something I've done.

Comment: Are atoms compressible? Of course. Everything is compressible, you just have to push hard enough. Conventional explosives can compress solid matter by about a factor of two in volume, I believe, magnetic fields in a pinch a little more. A nuclear explosion gets almost a factor of ten out of them, afterwards it gets a lot harder. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Ever seen a spring? They are everywhere.

What kind of material would you consider incompressible? Steel?

If you put a force on it (called "stress"), it will be squeezed by a certain amount (called "strain").
The ratio of the two is called "elastic modulus" (if you like big words).

In fact, if you have a rod of that material, and tap one end of it, sound travels from one end to the other, in the form of a wave of compression, which is nothing more than spring behavior.

So the idea that atoms are incompressible is *not so*.
They may be really stiff, compared to us jelly blobs, but they are compressible.

Comment: Ok, my question was more philosophical and theorical, obviusly things can be compressed, and technically the repulsion forces between electrons and protons will never let them join together, anyway thanks

Comment: @AntonioAguilar There are no "repulsion forces" between electrons and protons. Exactly the opposite.

Comment: @RobJeffries You are so correct, thanks for correcting I will edit that, I confused, I meant electrons and electrons.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

"Compressible" means "decreases in volume under applied pressure."  But "pressure" is by definition a macroscopic, thermodynamic property that is found by averaging over gigantic numbers of microscopic collisions.  It therefore doesn't make sense to talk about the "pressure" exerted on a single atom.  The "volume" of an atom is also not clearly defined due to the quantum-mechanical uncertainty at those scales.  So the "compressibility" of a single atom is not a well-defined concept.

Answer (score -1):

Atoms themselves cannot be compressed in general.

1. Liquids are not very compressible (they are compressible) because of distances between atoms. Gases have the most distance
   between atoms. Liquids have very little space in-between atoms, so when you press on them, the  their is not much more room to budge. Solids can budge because of there crystal structures.
2. Nothing is infinitely incompressible.
3. Infinite: black holes can have infinite density.

Comment: "Atoms themselves can't be compressed" - but after the collapse of a star the atoms can be stripped of their electrons leaving behind a neutron soup. This exotic form of matter, bound by gravitational forces of the mass can have incredible density.

Comment: @docscience That's why I said in general. And I wouldn't consider that compression, since you are removing part of the atom.